# Saving Chart as Image from Google Sheets and send to Dropbox - Saved Image seems broken - 0 bytes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropbox-api

I hope you are well.

I have the following code in apps script:

```
function uploadToDropbox(chartImage) {
    var url="https://content.dropboxapi.com";
    var options={
      "hostname": url,
      "method": "POST",
      "encoding": "utf8",
      "followRedirect": true,
      "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer DropboxAppTokenHere", 
                  "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                  "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/chart.png","mode": "overwrite","autorename": false,"mute": false,"strict_conflict": false}'
                 },
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
      'body': chartImage
    };
    var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/2/files/upload", options);
    var responseCode=response.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode != 200) {throw 'Error: ' + responseCode + " - " + response}
    var jsonResponse=JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }


function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var chartSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Score');
  var charts = chartSheet.getCharts();
  var chart = chartSheet.getCharts()[0];
  var chartImage = chart.getAs("image/png");

  //Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());
  if(sheet.getSheetName()=='Results Sample') {
  uploadToDropbox(chartImage);
  }
}
```

So, everything works good when I run the onEdit() function from the apps script editor and file is being sent to my desired DropBox folder. However, when I go and open the file on the folder I see the following:
[image]

Any ideas guys? Any parts that I am missing here? It seems that the connection between Google Sheets and DropBox works but I am doing something wrong on the saving of the file as an image/png.

Thanks in advance,

George!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var options={
  "hostname": url,
  "method": "POST",
  "encoding": "utf8",
  "followRedirect": true,
  "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer DropboxAppTokenHere", 
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
              "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/chart.png","mode": "overwrite","autorename": false,"mute": false,"strict_conflict": false}'
             },
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'body': chartImage
};
```

#### To:

```
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer DropboxAppTokenHere",
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/chart.png","mode": "overwrite","autorename": false,"mute": false,"strict_conflict": false}'
  },
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'payload': chartImage
};
```

#### Note:

- About `So, everything works good when I run the onEdit() function from the apps script editor and file is being sent to my desired DropBox folder. However, when I go and open the file on the folder I see the following:`, `onEdit` function is automatically run when the cell is edited. And, in the current stage, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` cannot be run by the simple trigger of OnEdit trigger. So, when the cell is edited, an error occurs by executing `onEdit` function. Please be careful about this.
- As the additional information, in your script, `chartImage` is Blob. When I tested uploading a binary file using Google Apps Script, in this API, it seems that both `'payload': Blob` and `'payload': ByteArray` can be used.
- And, as the additional information, in this case, `var chartImage = chart;` can be also used. Namely, it seems that `'payload': chart` can be used. If this is used in your showing script, the modified script is as follows.

```js
function uploadToDropbox(chart) {
  var url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com";
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer DropboxAppTokenHere",
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/chart.png","mode": "overwrite","autorename": false,"mute": false,"strict_conflict": false}'
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'payload': chart,
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/2/files/upload", options);
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (responseCode != 200) { throw 'Error: ' + responseCode + " - " + response }
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}

function sample() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var chartSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Score');
  var chart = chartSheet.getCharts()[0];
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Results Sample') {
    uploadToDropbox(chart);
  }
}
```

- As one more additional information, in this case, when a binary file is uploaded with `payload` of `UrlFetchApp`, it was found that both [Int8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array) and [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) can be used.
- When binary data is sent using `payload` of `UrlFetchApp`, it seems that the following situations can be used.

  | Number | Methods | Result |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | `payload: DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###")` | success |
  | 2 | `payload: DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob()` | success |
  | 3 | `payload: DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob().getBytes()` | success |
  | 4 | `payload: Int8Array.from(DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob().getBytes())` | success |
  | 5 | `payload: Uint8Array.from(DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob().getBytes())` | success |
  | 6 | `payload: DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob().getDataAsString()` | failure |

  - About number 1, in this case, `payload: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts()[0]` instead of `payload: DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###")` can be also used.
  - About number 4, each number of `DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob().getBytes()` and `Int8Array.from(DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob().getBytes())` are the same.
  - When I tested the numbers 4 and 5 to `UrlFetchApp` before, an error occurs. But, it was found that when I tested them again now, no error occurs.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hello @Tanaike and thank you so much for your comprehensive reply. The modified code snippet you sent me worked like a charm! Now I can see the image! I will also further read the reference link you sent above. Btw, as for the `onEdit()` function, I simply renamed that to `getTheImage()` and instead I placed a global trigger to run that On edit event!

Comment: @George Fragkos Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: sure! Btw, I saw that you give very good answers to people asking for issues on google apps script. I figured that out when I was searching for similar cases and I came across with your name several times! I was wondering if you could also have any ideas on the following topic of ours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052336/ . We just created that and it is again related to charts' strange behaviors. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Two items should be changed in your script:

1. In Google Apps Script, the POST body is always indicated by the key `payload`, rather than `body`.
2. The method `chart.getAs("image/png")` [returns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getascontenttype) a [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html) object, but this object reference will not be passed in the POST payload.  Instead, we need to convert it to raw data via [`.getBytes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getbytes).

Therefore, change this line:

```
'body': chartImage
```

to this:

```
'payload': chartImage.getBytes()
```

Comment: About `The method chart.getAs("image/png") returns a Blob object, but this object reference will not be passed in the POST payload.`, when I tested to upload a binary file as both `'payload': Blob` and `'payload': ByteArray`, both patterns can be correctly uploaded. When you tested it, `'payload': Blob` couldn't be uploaded?

Comment: Hello @Aaron! Thanks so much for your reply! The change you suggested did the trick! I can see the image properly on the DropBox folder! Thanks so much! It seems like I have 2 solutions on this thread of mine. Thank you so much guys! Can I mark both answers as correct?