# Updating Chart's Title via Apps Script resets all other options and break chart's preferred presentation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I hope everyone is well!

We are struggling for days now to fix this issue.

We have a chart on google sheet that seems the following way:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwolb3166xf8sov/This%20is%20the%20title%21.png?dl=0

After we execute the following code we found at the topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060874/ (Credit to [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)):

```
function title_new() {
  const updatedTitle = "### updated title ###";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const chart = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[3].charts[0];
  delete chart.position;
  chart.spec.title = updatedTitle;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: [{updateChartSpec: chart}]}, ssId);    
}
```

The chart will become the following way:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nq5wv2jeko3p53e/%23%23%23%20updated%20title%20%23%23%23.png?dl=0

So, the updating of the chart title is working properly, but at the same time we notice that other options like haxis, vaxis, etc., bring back to default which is something we do not want.

Please, are here any fixes to avoid the above behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your message of `I was wondering if you could also have any ideas on the following topic of ours`, I saw this question. About your showing script, if this is from my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060874 , first, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. Although unfortunately, I cannot know your actual chart, I'm worried that in this case, all values you want to keep might not be included in the returned value from `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get`. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike, please do not apologize, you are doing a great job and you do help us a lot! About your comment, how can I make sure that from `Sheets.Spreadsheet.get`, I get all values I want to keep?

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, although I'm not sure whether this is your expected direction, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster, I have just edited my initial post to follow communities' guidelines. Thank you so much for mentioning that and excuse me. Can you please verify that this is ok now? Thanks!

Comment: I've made some changes and it should be ok now.

Answer (score 1):

#### This might be a bug.

This issue was reported on Issue Tracker:

- [Updating Chart's Title via Apps Script resets all other options and break chart's preferred presentation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/253387834)

Anyone affected by this, consider [subscribing to this issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe).

Answer (score 0):

From your showing script, although unfortunately, I cannot know your actual chart, I'm worried that in this case, all values you want to keep might not be included in the returned value from `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get`. For example, how about including `fields` as follows?

#### From:

```
const chart = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[3].charts[0];
```

#### To:

```
const chart = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {fields: "sheets(charts)"}).sheets[3].charts[0];
```

If this was not the direct solution to your issue, how about using the Spreadsheet service (SpraedsheetApp) instead of Sheets API? When the Spreadsheet service is used, only the title might be able to be updated. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function title_new2() {
  const updatedTitle = "### updated title ###";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[3];
  const c = sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().setOption("title", updatedTitle).build();
  sheet.updateChart(c);
}
```

#### Note:

- Even when you tested the bottom script, when the same issue occurs, how about reporting it to the Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: Hello again @Tanaike. The second, alternative script you suggested is something that we initially had tried out and the output was the same. However, I just reported that on google as you suggested: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/253387834 . Finally, the first modification you proposed above to make the code row `const chart = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {fields: "sheets(charts)"}).sheets[3].charts[0];` also did not work...

Comment: Hi @GeorgeFragkos would you consider posting an answer referencing the issue you reported, in order to give it more visibility?

Comment: @George Fragkos Thank you for replying. About `The second, alternative script you suggested is something that we initially had tried out and the output was the same.`, from your question, I couldn't notice it. I apologize for this. About `const chart = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {fields: "sheets(charts)"}).sheets[3].charts[0]; also did not work`, in this case, it is considered that the values you want to keep are not included in the response value. So, I think that your issue tracker will be important.

Comment: @Tanaike, this is correct, after speaking with one friend developer of mine he also told me that the values I want to keep are not being included in the response value. We used `console.log(chart)` for that. So yes, let's see what Google will reply back. I will let you know once I have any responses from them. Thanks for all your help once again.